# How to dispose local control after leaving in a Method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a label created inside a method. Then I have a global string which changes the value from length 5 to 20 characters. strSuccess is declared globally.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //First Trial, didn't works
    Label lbl = new Label();
    Controls.Add(lbl);
    lbl.Location = new Point(locationX, locationY);
    lbl.Text = strSuccess;
    lbl.BringToFront();

    //Second Trial
    //I tried using but still didnt works
    Label lbl;
    using (lbl = new Label())
    {
        Controls.Add(lbl);
        lbl.Location = new Point(locationX, locationY);
        lbl.Text = strSuccess;
        lbl.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

The problem is when the value of strSuccess updates in every click of a button. Example: C# to Python; strSuccess=C# hon. It Overlaps. Because of each of user click of a button, a new label is created. So how to fixed or disposed properly locally created label. Creating global label and container is not an option.

Comment: Why are you even creating a new label each time ? Can't you just update the text of an already existing label (Or a label created once) ?

Comment: `//First Trial, didnt works` - define **didn't work**.

Comment: @user3185569 i created each time because i will use that label in that method only. i cant update the text because the previous local label is not properly dispose inside method. it must be like lbl.DisposeAfterLeavingMethod(); so if i click the button, im sure of it a new label will be created

Comment: @mjwills example strSuccess="cat"; then when strSuccess updates anywhere in my code, lets say strSuccess="hippopotamus". the result is strSuccess="cat opotamus". it overlaps

Comment: @Vincent I'm curious as to why you can't create a label and update its text. You say you can't create it because you "will use that label in that method only. i cant update the text because the previous local label is not properly dispose inside method" - so don't. Create a label with no content, and instead of generating a new one, set its `Content` property. If you need the label to be blank, set the content to `String.Empty`, or set its visibility to `Collapsed` or `Hidden`. I get that your approach isn't working the way you want, but it's not an efficient approach to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Creating global label and container is not an option.

Then you can query for your old control and dispose it:

```
const string lblName = "MySpecialName";
var oldLabel = Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == lblName);

Label lbl = new Label();
Controls.Add(lbl);
lbl.Name = lblName;
lbl.Location = new Point(locationX, locationY);
lbl.Text = strSuccess;
lbl.BringToFront();

if (oldLabel != null)
    oldLabel.Dispose();
```

I didn't get why you can't create a form field for that label and avoid creating and disposing controls every time. I highly recommend that you do that.

Comment: I'd place the dispose above the declaration for the new `Label` if it must always be disposed.

Comment: @Alex That's a try..finally.. I guess.

Comment: try..finally would do it. It's about the cleanest way to resolve the issue given the no global labels constraint.

Answer (score 2):

I realise you state that you can't create a global label, but this approach is much more simple, and unless there are very unusual circumstances, makes much more sense than generating multiple labels and trying to handle their deletion yourself.

```
  Label lbl;

  private void UpdateLabel(String text) {

      if (lbl == null) {
          lbl = new Label();
          lbl.Location = new Point(locationX, locationY);
          Controls.Add(lbl);
      }

      lbl.Text = text;
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     UpdateLabel(strSuccess);
  }
```

To clear the text, call `UpdateLabel(String.Empty);`

Whether you use the label in one method or one hundred, if you create it in the method and it goes out of scope, you need to look it up.

While this is possible, it's significantly slower than just updating it and adds complexity.